# Is there a way to install an OS to the hard disk when I have its VMDK file?

Tags: virtual-machine

I have a Linux-based operating system installed on a virtual machine and I have its VMDK file.
Can I install this OS as a standalone OS, working on a separate machine, using this VMDK file?

I made some configuration and settings on it, and now it's working as I want, so now I simply want to move it to a standalone machine.

Comment: This seems to be a guide: http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-2664

Answer (score 1):

Treat it the same way you'd treat any restore from one physical system to another physical system - Boot up the VM in vmware , image it as you would any system, say with [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) and restore it to the physical system.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have vmware tools inside VMDK? Then it is a no go, and in any way it is best to make fresh install and use VMDK just to get package lists, configurations and data.